# How to fix onclick in Phonegap/Android especially in lower versions of Android?

Tags: javascript, android, html, cordova, cordova-2.0.0

My onclick functionality works in Android devices versions 4, but not in lower versions.

I am facing a similar problem with the CSS `position:fixed` that did not work in Android devices with lower versions. The alternative I took up was iscroll, but I have yet to fix it up.

I am working in Phonegap/Android using Cordova 2.1.0 and Android 2.2.

My SQLITE plugin is compatible with Cordova 2.1.0.

**HTML**

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="scroller">
    <ul>
      <div id="header " class="header ">
        <div id="header_title" class="header_title"> </div>
        <div id="abc" class="abc"><img src="img/home.png" onClick="javascript:abc();"/></div>
      </div>
    </ul>
```

And another way of calling a page in Javascript is the following:

```
if(value_in_db==0) {
  document.getElementById("xyz").innerHTML = '<img src="img/inactive.png" />'
} else {
  document.getElementById("xyz").innerHTML = '<img src="img/active.png" onclick="xyz()"/> '
}
```

**In the Function**

```
function xyz(){
   window.location.href="index.html";
}
```

Images are positioned perfectly. But when I click, it does not call and very seldon it calls.

**Note:**

All the functionalities work in the higher versions except the devices with lower versions of Android say version 2.2.1.

Please do guide me! How can i fix this?

Answer (score -1):

Could you try to handle your click with the [addEventListener function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener)?

Comment: I am asking your opinion, will this work based on my this edited version of the question? I want to know your view and at the same time bit confused how to use this?